# Radio button value change onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to get value from radio button by onclick and I will use this value for sql query.
What should I do for this?

I want when I click on radio button I will get the value of the button and this value will work for sql query to change data or information

I use php and mysql.

```
<td><input type="radio" name="ac" value="AC"/>AC</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="ac" value="Non AC" />Non AC</td>
```

Comment: What did you try? Are you using a framework or plain simple javascript. How are you going to implement sql?  Via php, nodejs ruby etc etc.

Comment: I want when I click on radio button I will get the value of the button and this value will work for sql query to change data or information. I use php and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that you shouldn't use tabular elements for non-tabular data. But it makes sense using `label` element, and use `change` event instead of `click`.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <label><input type="radio" name="ac" value="AC"/>AC</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="ac" value="Non AC" />Non AC</label>
</div>
```

To get the value, you can use event delegation:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').onchange = function(e) {
    /* Maybe you should also check: e.target.type==='radio' */
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        var value = e.target.value;
        /* do something */
    }
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMZ6k/)

Another possibility is creating an event listener for each radio:

```
var els = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('input'),
    handler = function() {
        var value = this.value;
        /* do something */
    };
for(var i = 0; i<els.length; ++i) {
    els[i].onchange = handler;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMZ6k/1/)